# Suppress error message in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code. When executed it prints

> *Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 17
>
>   Column '@t.Country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained
>   in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ERROR'*

But I want only `'ERROR'` to be printed. Is there a way to suppress the error message?

Thanks
Satyaprakash J

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
    DECLARE @t TABLE
        (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,Country NVARCHAR(50)
        ,Year INT
        ,PopulationInMillions INT
        )

    INSERT @t (Country, Year, PopulationInMillions)
    VALUES ('US', 2000, 20),
           ('US', 2001, 22) 

    SELECT Country, MAX(PopulationInMillions)
    FROM @t       
GO

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC Test
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
END CATCH
```

Comment: The error is sent from the `CREATE PROC` not the `EXEC`

Answer (score 1):

If the error actually *occurs* inside of the `TRY` block, then yes, you can - exactly as you've shown:

```
BEGIN TRY
    RAISERROR('Hello!',16,1)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
END CATCH
```

Just prints `ERROR`. Similarly:

```
create procedure P
AS
    RAISERROR('World!',16,1)
GO
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC P
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
END CATCH
```

Also just prints `ERROR`.

But, as others have tried to tell you, it doesn't matter how you structure your `TRY`/`CATCH` if the error is occurring before they're ever entered. And there's no simple way to *create* a procedure within a `TRY`/`CATCH`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to suppress the error message?

**Yes, there is.**

Fix your query:

```
SELECT Country, MAX(PopulationInMillions)
FROM @t
```

Like so:

- Add `GROUP BY country` like so:

  ```
  SELECT Country, MAX(PopulationInMillions)
  FROM @t 
  GROUP BY Country;
  ```

  Or,
- Use an aggregate function with `Country`:

  ```
  SELECT Max(Country), MAX(PopulationInMillions)
  FROM @t
  ```

  Or,
- Remove the `Country` field from the `SELECT` list:

  ```
  SELECT MAX(PopulationInMillions)
  FROM @t
  ```

I think you need to read more about how the [**`GROUP BY`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) clause works. It is crucial to understand how grouping works in SQL.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, My problem is not the stored procedure. I dont want to fix the stored procedure. I want to modify the message displayed.

Comment: @SatyaprakashJ - But why you got the error code you got, if there is no problems with your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the stored procedure creation statement as above is the only way you can suppress the error message.

The create procedure statement is raising the error due to the syntax being wrong.  The stored procedure is never created in the database.  The begin try is not executing a stored procedure as the procedure does not exist.  You could put EXEC {anything} in the try to get the text error displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

The main issue is, as [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) pointed out, your error is coming from the `create procedure` statement. Not from `exec`. To elaborate further, it is a **Parsing and Compilation** error indicating you cannot select a column and an aggregate function with out group by(ing) it. Do this.

```
SELECT Country, MAX(PopulationInMillions)
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY Country --add this line
```

but even if you (try to) do

```
begin try
    DECLARE @t TABLE
        (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,Country NVARCHAR(50)
        ,Year INT
        ,PopulationInMillions INT
        )

    INSERT @t (Country, Year, PopulationInMillions)
    VALUES ('US', 2000, 20),
           ('US', 2001, 22) 

    print N'Before error';

    SELECT Country, MAX(PopulationInMillions)
    FROM @t
    --GROUP BY Country    --comment in attempt to cause error

    print N'After error';

end try
begin catch
    print N'Caught error';
end catch
```

You won't even get to `print N'Before error';` Because the error Msg 8120 is a **fatal error** returned at parse and compile time. The whole batch is not even executed.

Here's a good article on understanding how queries are processed http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/

And here's a good article from the times there weren't TRY...CATCH yet. But a good source for understanding fatal/non-fatal sql errors. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/handling-errors-in-stored-procedures